# php file uploading and storing

Tags: php, authorization, download, file-upload

1. I  want to upload a file on my PHP server. I am currently able to upload it on server using the following code but I don't know how I can store it on the server.
   How can I store the file in a specific directory?
2. I also want the users to be able to download the files but only once they log in not before that.

   For example i store the file in directory */myfiles* no-one must be able to download it 
   unless he is logged in

   e.g. someone can download the file if he knows the file location
   like *www.example.com/temp/myfile.txt*

   I don't want that - user must not be able to download it unless he is logged in.
3. I have one page *B.php* in which there will be the download link. When the user clicks on that link he must be able to download the file. In short, he must get a *Save as/Open* pop up of browser when he clicks my link. How do I do that?

Comment: @gumbo : how do i accpe the answer posted my someone?Where is the option for that?

Comment: @unknown: Go to one of your questions and click the check mark next to a question you want to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Check the PHP documentation about **move_uploaded_file()** here: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function UploadData()
{
        $yourpath ="yourfoldername";
    createafolder($yourpath ); // if not present then create it (its custom function)

    $target_path = $yourpath . basename( $_FILES['fileupload']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
               //write if any processing
    }
            else echo "Upload sucessful!";

}
```